# Factoring input to listed frequencies

Tags: python, list, binary, counter, calculator

I am trying to write a function where it calculates the lowest possible coin-change return for a value e.g. you could give 0.70 with a 0.50 + 0.20.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
def pay_with_coins( amount ):
amount = float()
numberof200 = 2.00
numberof100 = 1.00
numberof050 = 0.50
numberof020 = 0.20
numberof010 = 0.10
numberof005 = 0.05
numberof002 = 0.02
numberof001 = 0.01
change = []
no200counter = amount.count(numberof200)
no100counter = amount.count(numberof100)
no050counter = amount.count(numberof050)
no020counter = amount.count(numberof020)
no010counter = amount.count(numberof010)
no005counter = amount.count(numberof005)
no002counter = amount.count(numberof002)
no001counter = amount.count(numberof001)
numberofchange = no200counter + no100counter + no050counter + no020counter + no010counter + no005counter + no002counter + no001counter

if no200counter > 0: +1
elif no100counter > 0: +1
elif no050counter > 0: +1
elif no020counter > 0: +1
elif no010counter > 0: +1
elif no005counter > 0: +1
elif no002counter > 0: +1
elif no001counter > 0: +1

change.append(numberofchange)
return list(change)
```

What I have tried doing in my code with the if statements is that it checks to see if the next largest change value can be factored into our amount, adding one at the indices in my list which should return in the end, moving onto the next largest change value available when the current one no longer can factor into our amount (this is better illustrated in an example I have given below).

An issue I have run into is that my console says 'float' object has no attribute 'count', but I am wanting to make sure that the amount is a 2dp float.

I want to list the output value in the format where the values are [2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01] and each element increases depending on how much of it there. So, an output without input should be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

If we were to find the change to the above example (0.70) I would like my output to be:

[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Another example would be to find the change of 5.18. The output should be:

[2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

The way I want to list my final output is **somewhat** similar to binary conversion, except each 'bit' can exceed 1 if needed.

As you can see, I have an idea of how I want to code it, but I am just struggling with how to actually put it together. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve your problem. Let me know how this worked out

```
def pay_with_coins( amount ):
    allCoins = [2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

    change = []
    for coin in allCoins:
        # Find out how many maximum coins can fit into the amount. Ex for amount 5 a max of 2 coins of value 2 can fit
        n = (int)(amount / coin)
        change.append(n)
        # Substract the value of amount for which change is generated. 
        # Ex - for amount 5, and coin 2, $4 change will be generated and balance left will be $1
        amount = round(amount - (n * coin), 2)     # Rounding to 2 decimals

    return change

print(pay_with_coins(5.18))
Output - > [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: the output doesn't return a list, so for the example you used 5.18 just printed 518

Comment: nevermind, found some errors in the way i implemented your help and it worked, thanks for the help